# C memory allocate

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct data
{
    char a[100*1024];
};

struct test
{
    void * pc;
    struct test * next;
};

struct data dd; 
struct data * pd = &dd;

void *mall(struct data *p) 
{
    return (void *)(&(p->a[0]));
}

int main(void)
{
    struct test * p = mall(pd);
    p->pc = "testasdfsadfasdfasdfasdfsadfsadfsadfsadfsadfsadfsadfsadfasdfsadfsadfsadfsadfsadfasdfsadfsadfsadfsadf";
   printf("%p\n%p\n", &dd.a[0], p->pc); // <-- line 27
   return 0;
}
```

I don't understand how is the memory allocated to p in main, I think there is no memory allocated to p->pc, however the program could run properly. if you think the memory is the global array, then how come the output of line 27 is not the same?

Comment: try to print the addresses.

Comment: Invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: I have done that already. address of p is the same with a, but not pc. And dd.a[0] is not assigned any value. So I don't know where is the content of p->pc stored.

Answer (score 1):

> how come the output of line 27 is not the same?

In "line 27"

- `&dd.a[0]` evaluates to the address of `dd.a`'s first element.
- `p->pc` *holds* the address of the string literal `"testasdfsadfasdfasdfas..."` as assigned in this line

  ```
  p->pc = "testasdfsadfasdfasdfas...";
  ```

(You are aware one cannot assign arrays in C, aren't you?)

Comment: Sir , if you print `&p->pc` then you would get same addresses .

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything in the stack. So you aren't needing to malloc anything to the heap. You don't segfault because your program still has access to the memory you assigned your string to (accounting for the fact that you can't assign strings).